# Bootstrap Modal auto height issue

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-modal, bxslider

I developed box slider with ajax and bootstrap modal popup. But issue is do not take default height of images and display as below.
[image]

When I resize window then it display proper in screen.  My question is how to forcefully trigger window resize function to solve my problem?

> Note : When I press f12 or resize window then it work perfect. But initially loaded as given in screenshot.

**AJAX Calling**

```
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: URL,
                data: {id: id},
                success: function (result) {
                    $(".modal-body").html('<ul class="bxslider"></ul>');
                    $(".bxslider").append(result);
                    $('.bxslider').bxSlider();
                },
                complete: function (result) {
                     $(window).trigger('resize');
                }
            });
```

Comment: `$(window).trigger('resize')`.. Man you have enough reputation to know how to assist a question with code or what you have tried right.. ?

Comment: Add `img-responsive` class in your images `<img src="image1.jpg" class="img-responsive">`

Comment: @GuruprasadRao I already tried with `$(window).trigger('resize')` and possibilities then I ask here.

Comment: Could you replicate it in fiddle?

Comment: @GuruprasadRao I cant do that because problem is images are loaded dynamically using `ajax`.

Comment: Call `resize` event after image `load` event

Comment: @sushmit.patil I already trigger `$(window).trigger('resize')` after image loaded.

Comment: Is that some kind of `slider` inside `modal`? any plugin used?

Comment: @Sadikhasan After ajax call?

Comment: @GuruprasadRao Yes, I used `boxslider` in `modal`.

Comment: Did you re-initiate it? Can you show your `ajax` call??

Comment: @sushmit.patil After ajax success event I trigger `resize` function.

Comment: It's difficult to tell without any HTML markup or fiddle, but you could try initializing the boxslider after the modal is shown, as in $('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) { ... })

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
         $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: URL,
            data: {id: id},
            success: function (result) {
                $(".modal-body").html('<ul class="bxslider"></ul>');
                $(".bxslider").append(result);
                     $(".bxslider image").load(function(){
                     $(window).trigger('resize');
                 });
                $('.bxslider').bxSlider();
            },
            complete: function (result) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: try to implement same in `success` method